# how to prevent jdbc from trying to connect to a mysql database during unit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, jdbc, mocking

I'm making an application for a school project, but I'm running into the issue that when I try to run the unit tests that it tries to connect to the database while starting up the application, which isn't required for the tests (because it will be mocked), and is not available in the CI/CD pipeline.

[jdbc connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpQ4t.png)

I'm building my project in Java Maven Springboot and would like to know how I can prevent it from trying to connect to the database when running my test.

here is a link to my repository: https://gitlab.com/kwetter_jack/Kwetter_posts/-/tree/ci_cd_setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while I was investigating the spring boot H2 in-memory database (as suggested by Chris Olive and Paranaaan) I also came across the option of using a test container. after looking into this I saw that this enables the project to create a temp docker container with a MySQL image that I can use during the testing of my project, considering I was planning on using docker anyway for the integration testing of my microservices project I attempted this and it worked as I had hoped it would.

if anyone is interested in the test container solution that I used, the information can be found here:

https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mysql/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your test classes have `@SpringBootTest` annotation which will start a Spring application context - as your application uses a database the tests will also try to setup and use a database connection.

The simplest solution is to remove the annotation so the tests no longer try to connect to a database. You'll probably need to mock some more dependencies as a result as Spring is no longer creating these for you. You could also have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing for some other ideas how you could alter your tests.

Alternatively if you do want / need the application context to run you can add a `application.yaml` for the tests that defines and uses a in memory DB so the tests have something to connect to - see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database for details how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change value under `spring.datasource` to `H2 database` to prevent
The application connect the real database.

[Test application.yml](https://gitlab.com/kwetter_jack/Kwetter_posts/-/blob/ci_cd_setup/src/test/resources/application.yaml)

FYI, You no need to copy all config from original application.yml, just only some config that you need to override.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out to me I was under the assumption that it would need to know everything in the test application.yml as well